# How to add child row to parent record in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

```
var data = [{
"_id": "5814c04ca105fa8eb6e3e08a",
"name": "aa33",
"address": "bb33",
"updateby": "matt",
"Histories": [{
    "svr_id": "a1122",
    "details": "well",
    "updateby": "matt",
    "_id": "5814c5cdb41151ca54871f5d"
}],
"lastupdate": "2016-11-03T11:18:26.000Z"
}]
```

I am new in Angularjs. I have data in mongo database. Everything works fine in CRUD for parent level only. If I have child level "Histories" shown above , how can I add another new child row in Histories node.

Thanks

Comment: `data[0].Histories.push(newRow);`

Answer (score 0):

Because you've defined your objects as arrays, you must access them as such. To add a new key/value to Histories, please do this:

```
data[0].Histories[0].newKey = "newVal";
```

Comment: Please kindly provide more detail steps to achieve, many thanks.

Comment: @MatthewWong Just add my line wherever you want to add a new child row. Replace `newKey` with whatever key you want, and `newVal` with whatever value you want. You have to be more specific if you need more help.